# navigation pane react javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications

I have a quick question about a navigation pane in my app.js file. What I need is an onclick function that'll render the page that it is intended to be routed to, while staying within the confines on the app.js file. My default page should be the Form page, which is what is rendered initially, but I cannot seem to figure out why when the navigation panel is clicked, it is not rendering the page that I would like it to. Any help would be much appreciated. Also, please note.. Below is my code:

```
class App extends Component {
render() { 
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <button type="submit" class="Adminfont">Admin Page</button>
      <div className="App-header">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo"/>
      <img src={filler} className="filler" alt="filler"/>
      <img src={logo2} className="App-logo" alt="logo2"/>
    </div>
    <Form />
    <div class="navpane" id="mynav">
      <a href="Form">Report<br />Food</a>
      <a href= "Events">FRN<br />Events</a>
      <a href="About">About<br />Us</a>
    </div>
    </div>
   );
  }
 }
export default App;
```

Comment: Use [tag:react-router] maybe.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @chris, what you need may be 'react-router' (or any other routing library). Hope this code helps you understand.

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Form</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/events">Events</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <hr/>

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/events" component={Events}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
);

const Form = () => (<div>Form Page</div>);
const Events = () => (<div>Events Page</div>);
const About = () => (<div>About Page</div>);


export default App;
```

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start for more info on 'react-router'.